# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some attribute to an element with some jQuery, but I'm getting a syntax error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery('.mit div')
           .attr({data-slick:'{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'
          });
</script>
```

I need to have a result as this below when working with slick slide.

```
<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
```

Comment: try `'data-slick'`, the `-` in JS is used for subtraction and so it is not valid in an identifier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a `-` in a JavaScript object key. If you need one, then you have to escape it with `"` or `'`:

```js
jQuery('.mit div')
  .attr({'data-slick':'{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'
});
```

Comment: Now the error is gone, but still can figure out how to get <div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'> instead of <div data-slick="{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 1}">

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get `data-slick` from your div or set it?

Comment: I'm working on a little carousel for products and the products container is generated through another plugin, and by adding the data-slick to the container, the slider will work fine. [link](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) `<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>`